# How can i save an element from a cell array into a normal array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

i have the code below :

```
if encoded(i)==code1(2,j)
```

that is a simple line and basically i want to save a specific element from a cell array named `code1` into another array named `encoded`. The problem here is that matlab shows the below message:

Undefined operator `==` for input arguments of type `cell`.
Is there any solution to this problem? How can i save an element from a cell array into a normal array in MATLAB?

Comment: Use curly braces: `code1{2,j}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function cellfun. Depending on the type of data in code1{2,j}, the first argument of the cellfun should be an appropriate function.

For example, if code1{2,j} is a string, use

```
cellfun(@str2double, code1{2,j})
```

Alternatively, if code1{2,j} is an array, use cell2mat as

```
cell2mat(code1{2,j})
```

Comment: if both encoded and code1 are cell arrays what should i do then?

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΓιαννάκος A [mre] added to your question would be very helpful in providing a relevant answer.